# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE - getting "Integrity constraint violation"

Tags: mysql

I have a table...

```
CREATE TABLE `pricing` (
    `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `seller_id` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `price` float DEFAULT NULL,
    `ship` float DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`),
    KEY `seller_id` (`seller_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

And when I try to run an `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, I get an integrity constraint violation, if I try to edit `seller_id`:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '4984-2014-11-23 10:05:20' for key 'PRIMARY'.
```

The SQL query is:

```
INSERT INTO pricing
       (product_id, price, ship, seller_id) 
VALUES (:product_id, :price, :ship, :seller_id) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    seller_id = :seller_id
```

Is that desired behavior? Is there a way to avoid it? We're using `REPLACE` for now, but I'm curious as to whether I am doing something wrong or not. I'm not updating the primary key mind you, but another regular non-unique key - and the constraint falls on the primary key.

What is the process that's going on here?

**EDIT:** I ran an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a9caa/1) and it works okay. Why would it cause errors on my machine? :/

Comment: (1) Are you sure the entire query is being run?  (If the query does not include the `ON DUPLICATE KEY . . . ` part it would fail with this error.) (2) Are there any other unique keys or unique indexes?

Comment: (1) yes, because when I change it to update another field - for example price - it works flawlessly. (2) Nope, the `CREATE TABLE` query I posted is accurate and there are no other keys or indices.

Comment: The query works just fine for the mysql server I am running. What are you using to execute the query?  Can whatever you use to execute it handle 2 equally named placeholders? And the dot after the last seller_id, is that just a copy/paste error or is it there in the real query? Last of all is the primary key only the product_id? If so, are there any foreign keys from other tables perhaps pointing to this table, or perhaps are there triggers which get activated when updating the table pricing (or one or more of its columns)

Comment: The . is a copy/paste issue - it's not really there. It runs with PDO so yeah it should be able to handle replacing the same parameters twice/more.

Comment: **off topic note**; I recommend that you do this: `seller_id = values(seller_id)` instead of `seller_id = :seller_id`. Basically that says take the value that was passed in and use that for the update. It is one less future error you may have to deal with. **Note** I removed the semicolon on purpose, as it is no longer needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query you listed with that table works fine for me, so the error is not in there.

Upon taking a closer look at the error however I notice the following:

> Duplicate entry '4984-2014-11-23 10:05:20' for key 'PRIMARY'.

This PRIMARY key looks a lot like a number followed by a datetime, which it most likely is. Most likely there is for example a trigger on the mysql database for this table.

(Based on the id+date I'd say probally something to keep track of price changes automatically?)

Another option is the possibility that there is a foreign key issue, though based on the error that is not likely.

Try running the following mysql statement in the database of the table and take a look at the result.

```
SHOW TRIGGERS
```

Comment: You're right, there's a related trigger, and the constraint violation is there. I was stupid not to think of that. Thank you!

Comment: If the trigger is a on insert, before, try changing it to after insert. That way it will only get executed if there is an actual new insert. (I assume that at this moment the trigger runs on (before on insert, on/after update).