# "insert ... on duplicate key update" query works on phpmyadmin but not in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I've seen similar posts but none of the answers helped me... I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_likes_name` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_name` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `like` enum('yes','no','ask_later') NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `provenance` enum('elimination','selection','suggestion') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `avis_user` (`id_user`,`id_name`),
  KEY `id_user` (`id_user`,`id_name`)
)
```

And I use this query:

```
INSERT INTO user_likes_name (id_user, id_name, `like`)
VALUES (?, ?, 'ask_later')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `date` = current_timestamp
```

Which works fine on phpmyadmin.
But when I use it in my code (with PDO) I get this error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicata du
>   champ '99-869' pour la clef 'avis_user'' in C:\fakepath.php on line 95

My PHP code is:

```
$req = $bdd->prepare("
    INSERT INTO user_likes_name (id_user, id_name, `like`)
    VALUES (?, ?, 'ask_later')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `date` = current_timestamp");
$req->execute(array($foo, $bar));
```

I feel like I'm going kwayzey. Am I?

Comment: The error message should tell you what the problem is. It looks like you are trying to insert data which violates a unique key. Post your schema and a sample of the data you are inserting. But you should check the data you are inserting against what's in the table.

Comment: could be a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27091190/on-duplicate-key-update-getting-integrity-constraint-violation

Comment: error seems clear, what dont you understand?

Comment: Why do you have `UNIQUE KEY \`avis_user\`` AND `KEY \`id_user\`` with the same conditions? It is possible that `->prepare()` is hitting an Integrity constraint due to the double keys, that doesn't happen in phpmyadmin

Comment: try to replace `current_timestamp` by `current_timestamp()` or by `NOW()`

Comment: Sound silly, right? I totally agree. The thing is, the very same query, on the very same database, with the very same data, works on phpmyadmin and doesn't work when I execute it with PDO.

Comment: PHPAdmin can modify query to make it workable

Comment: @Sean alright, the second key wasn't useful so I deleted it. Still doesn't work.

Comment: I tried to change the values of my update but it seem to not be the origin of the problem @AlexandrKapustin

Answer (score 0):

Two hours of work later, I realized I wasn't actually working on the right file. It's hard to overstate the way I'm feeling jaded right now.

Comment: We've all been there.  Keep on truckin'